# Creating Table Error With Syntax

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a table in a database, I am using mysql 5.5 (im using myphpadmin in MAMP) below is my table, I have been using the mysql manual and it seems like everything here is as it should be? but i keep getting this error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''users'( 'id' int UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, 'username' VAR' at line 1

```
CREATE TABLE 'users'(
 'id' int UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
 'username' VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL, 
 'password' VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
 'name'VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
 'entry'text NOT NULL,
 'date_created' timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  key('username')
  );
```

Comment: Please don't SHOUT WHEN ASKING YOUR QUESTIONS. Posting in all CAPS makes your question harder to read. The Shift key was invented for a reason. :-) Tag info should be just added in tags, and not put in the subject as well; the tag system works very well without being helped. Thanks. :-)

Comment: ;-) Shouting at us because you're frustrated probably isn't the best idea when you want us to help you. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use backticks instead of single quotes:

```
CREATE TABLE `users`(
 `id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
 `username` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL, 
 `password` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
 `name` VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
 `entry` text NOT NULL,
 `date_created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  key(`username`)
  );
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2e25).

*Note:* or use no backticks at all:

```
CREATE TABLE users(
 id int UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
 username VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL, 
 password VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
 name VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
 entry text NOT NULL,
 date_created timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  key(username)
  );
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d9ee7)

Comment: No backticks (i.e. quoting) at all would even be better.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name agreed, posted that version as well. :)

Comment: what is the point of backticks if they're not required, does it just make it easier to read?

Comment: @user1905577 You'll need to quote them with backticks if the column/table name is the same as a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html) such as `limit` or `current_date` or something.